# How do I know when to end a solo journaling game?

Tags: solo, journaling-game, dungeon-wordle

I picked up [Dungeon Wordle](https://mirimetamagic.itch.io/dungeon-wordle) from the [Wordle Jam on itch.io](https://itch.io/physical-games/tag-wordlejam), and I was really impressed.

I've only 'played' for one day, I'm defeating the sun, so I can become darkness.

I got *Take the win, already.* and the chest contained (based on that day's solution to Wordle) a:

> Tiny Necklace of Youth.

But I don't know how judge when I'm finished?

The pdf says:

> Ending The Game: The game could end when your adventurer defeats
> their foe(s), or when they become who they truly want to be, or both. Or
> it could end when they have no chance of redemption.
> Or like, whenever you want, really…

But I've not played a journaling game, so I don't have a good baseline.

How do I decide when the game is over? When I'm bored?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### "Wanting it to end" should be read as a positive action on your part.

That is to say, "having an ending in mind and working towards it, even if it isn't one of the more obvious end points", as opposed to the more passive/negative "not wanting to play the game anymore".

You **can** "end the game" that way, nobody's going to stop you, and if you're really feeling significant friction keeping up with the journaling, you probably should?

But a journaling game is a way to challenge yourself to write something, even a little bit of something, that you're not writing right now. Like all challenges there's probably going to be a little friction now and then, and if you work through it when you can, it can be very satisfying.

Comment: Ah ok, I was approaching 'Describe how' to be in a technical or non-diegetic way. Is the purpose of most journaling games more 'in-character' writing?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yes, most journaling games are intended to be approached from the viewpoint of a particular journal writer. Sometimes that's the actual you, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 5):

In some kind of way, the problem you face is similar to [closing a novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/41689), so I will partially quote from my own answer over at writing.se:

> What are you going to tell? Is it a (maybe short) story that has everything told by now or do you still have 3 acts to tell? Let your tale guide your writing, then use the Red Ink later.

Your character has goals and plans. There are adversaries. They found the necklace of youth. Is the artifact the magical McGuffin that solves all the problems or the one thing they set out to acquire and now they can retire forever young? Is it just another tool to get the character into trouble and have the same or a new adversary show up and harass them? It's your tale! Explore the possibilities and then decide how much you want to do with the artifact!

And if you are content with ending the story right there: do yourself a favor and at least think about tying up some loose ends, maybe in an epilogue of sorts. Or maybe tell the reader that the journal aborts at that point and how/when it was discovered?

In a somewhat silly example, I have recently listened to the [journalling of a Dwarf Fortress player in adventure mode](https://youtu.be/OLqTErDncH8). He sent out his character on the quest to gather a mythic slab, encountered different foes of their own species, then a town that was populated with what was normally considered enemy species but those were friendly and pointed the protagonist to the right location. There they carefully stalked the ruins for the slab, fining one but not the right one before they encountered the Evil Beast. The journal goes on to describe the flight from the EB, before they, just by chance, stumble over the right artifact. They pick it up and flee from the caverns and only once they make it outside, they read the slab. And that's where the journal breaks off. Yes, the story of *this journal* ends there.

However, the story of the character goes on a little further: they get back home, deliver the slab and then die a broken being - the message on the slab seems to have broken their spirit.